# AttributeError at /login/: Manager isn't accessible via User instances

Tags: python, django

I have created a python file in my django project with thhe name of signals.py in which i have created two function with are given below:

and then I have imported these to functions into userss app(it is my second app name of the project and I am working on it currently)), which is given below:

When I remove all these functions then it works properly but it doesn't save the new users into database but when I include them then it gives the error which I mention earlier.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=user)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.objects.save()

class UserssConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'userss'

    def ready(self):
        import userss.signals
```

Comment: It should be `instance.save()` not `instance.objects.save()`.\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your signals you write:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.objects.save()
```

If you want to save the profile, then it should be:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

or the `related_name` you passed to the `OneToOneField` or `ForeignKey` from `Profile` to `User`.